# WinForms Container to display a single child

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking for a container that can display content, however I'd like to avoid using e.g panel, having to clear/add child. Is there a control that fits the description or would I need to create a custom container ( using e.g the mentioned panel ), exposing some "Content" property, handling the logic within there?

Comment: A panel is the container.

Comment: @aush yeah, but panel has children, not a child. Thus when assigning a child, I'd have to clear it's children and add the new child. If that was the case I'd create a custom control that would do that for me. What I'm asking tho is, whether there's already a container that is a "single child" oriented or not.

Comment: you can have custom control derived from ContainerControl and extend those functions which you need some control over them.

Comment: *Every* WinForms control has "children, not child" -- the `Controls` property is introduced on the base `Control` class, so every control has a collection of children. WPF behaves more like what you're looking for; the only WPF controls that can have multiple children are those that do specific layouts, and everything else has one child (or none). Nothing like that exists in WinForms.

Comment: There is little reason to fret about this.  You can simply expose Controls[0] as a Content property.  That doesn't stop anybody from adding more but controls are always private implementation details so that just doesn't matter.

Comment: @JoeWhite thanks for the explanation, mind answering the question with what you just said? So I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Every* WinForms control has "children, not child" -- the Controls property is introduced on the base Control class, so every control has a collection of children.

WPF behaves more like what you're looking for; the only WPF controls that can have multiple children are those that do specific layouts, and everything else has one child (or none).

Nothing like that exists in WinForms.